# Laravel: при изменении роута страница стала недоступна

Tags: php, laravel

В роутах изменил страницу с:

```
Route::get('/photo', 'MediaController@photo_index')->name('media.photo');
```

на

```
Route::get('/media/photo', 'MediaController@photo_index')->name('media.photo');
```

После чего страница */media/photo* стала выдавать 404 ошибку.

В чем может быть проблема?  Как сделать, чтобы страница перестала выдавать 404.
Кэш роута почистил, не помогло.
Вот routes.php

```
Route::resource('/poll', 'PollController@update');

Route::group(['prefix' => '','middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect','web','localeGeoRedirect','localeOtherModules','seo']], function() {
    Route::get( '/conference', 'ConferenceController@index' )->name( 'conference' );
    Route::get( '/promo/{promo_name}', 'PromoPageController@show' )->name( 'promo' );
});

Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect','web','localeGeoRedirect','localeOtherModules','seo']], function() {

    Route::get('/fight_voting','FightForecastController@index')->name('fight_voting');
    Route::get('/vote/{user_id}/{fight_id}','FightForecastController@vote');
    Route::get('/current_time',function(){return date('d/m/Y, H:i:s');});
    Route::get('/home',function(){return redirect('/user');});
    Route::get('/', 'PromoController@index')->name('home');
//  Route::resource('/poll', 'PollController@update');
    Route::get('/404.html', function () {
        return Response::view('pages.acb.errors.404', [],404);
//      return redirect('/404.html',301);
    });

    Route::get('/moderation_comments', function () {
        return view('admin.moderation_comments');
    });

    //tournaments
    Route::get('/tournaments', 'TournamentsController@index')->name('tournaments');          //show more button, JSON callback
    Route::get('/tournamentprev/{slug}_{id}', 'TournamentsController@prev')->name('tournaments.prev');
    Route::get('/tournamentnext/{slug}_{id}', 'TournamentsController@next')->name('tournaments.next');
    Route::get('/tournament-promo/{slug}_{id}', 'TournamentsController@next')->name('tournaments.next_promo');
    //fighters
    Route::get('/fighters', 'FightersController@index')->name('fighters');
    Route::get('/fighters_ranks', 'FighterRankController@index')->name('fighters_rank');
    Route::get('/fighters/{slug}_{id}', 'FightersController@show')->name('fighter');
    Route::get('/morefighters', 'FightersController@more_fighters')->name('fighters.more');
    Route::get('/morefights', 'FightersController@more_fights')->name('fights.more');
    Route::get('/sortfighters/{weight_category_id}', 'FightersController@sort')->name('fighters.sort');
    Route::get('/setsortfighters/{form}/{weight_category_id}', 'FightersController@more_sorted_fighters')->name('fighters.sort.set');
    Route::get('/career', 'CareerController@index')->name('career');
    //news
    Route::get('/news', 'NewsController@index')->name('news');          //show more button, JSON callback
    Route::get('/news/{slug}_{id}', 'NewsController@show')->name('news.show');
    Route::get('/news/sort/{category_id}', 'NewsController@sort')->name('next.sort');
    Route::get('/morenews', 'NewsController@more')->name('news.more');
    //media
//    Route::get('/media', 'MediaController@index')->name('media');

    //media photo
    Route::get('/photo', 'MediaController@photo_index')->name('media.photo');
    Route::get('/photo/{photoCategory}', 'MediaController@photo')->name('media.photo_category');
    Route::get('/photo/{photoCategory}/{slug}', 'MediaController@photo_album')->name('media.photo.album');

    //media video
    Route::get('/video', 'MediaController@video_index')->name('media.video');
    Route::get('/video/{videoCategory}', 'MediaController@video')->name('media.video_category');
    Route::get('/video/{videoCategory}/{slug}_{id}', 'MediaController@video_show')->name('media.video_show');

    Route::get('/sort/{type}/{category_id}', 'MediaController@sort')->name('media.sort');

    Route::get('/album/{slug}_{id}', 'MediaController@album')->name('album');
    Route::get('/morealbums/{from}', 'MediaController@more_albums')->name('album.more');
    Route::get('/sortedalbums/{category}', 'MediaController@sorted_albums')->name('album.sorted');
    Route::get('/moresortedphotoalbums/{from}/{category}', 'MediaController@more_sorted_albums')->name('album.sorted.more');
    Route::get('/path_array/{id}', 'MediaController@as_array')->name('media.path_array');

    Route::get('/sortedphotos/{category}', 'MediaController@sorted_photos')->name('media.sorted_photos');
    Route::get('/moresortedphotos/{from}/{category}', 'MediaController@more_sorted_photos')->name('media.sorted_photos.from');

    Route::get('/morevideos/{from}', 'MediaController@more_videos')->name('media.more_videos');
    Route::get('/moresortedvideos/{from}/{category}', 'MediaController@more_sorted_videos')->name('media.more_videos.from');
    //static pages
    Route::get('/tickets', 'TicketsController@index')->name('tickets');
    Route::get('/history', function () {
        return view('pages.acb.history.history');
    })->name('static.history');
    Route::get('/partnership', function () {
        return redirect('/',301);
        //return redirect('/cooperation', 301);tournamentnext/acb-67-gr
    });
     //redirect
    Route::get('/tournamentnext/acb-90-kazan-acfmrz07_107?utm_source=zemedia_vk&utm_medium=cpm&utm_campaign=tickets-acb-vkontakte-mma_w3_m_18up-post_public-KZ100-all&utm_content=poster_395955', function(){
      return redirect('/tournaments', 301);
    });
    Route::get('/cooperation', function () {
        return redirect('/',301);
        //return view('pages.partnership');
    });
    Route::get('/partners', function () {
        return view('pages.acb.partners.partners');
    })->name('static.partners');
    Route::get('/mission', function () {
        return view('pages.acb.mission.mission');
    })->name('static.mission');
    Route::get('/team', function () {
        return view('pages.acb.team.team');
    })->name('static.team');
    Route::get('/contact', function () {
        return view('pages.acb.contact.contact');
    })->name('static.contact');
    Route::get('/idea', function(){
        return view('pages.acb.idea.idea');
    })->name('static.idea');
    Route::get('/fans', function(){
        return "no page";
    })->name('fans');
    Route::get('/privacy', function(){
        return view('pages.totalizator.privacy.privacy');
    })->name('privacy');
    Route::get('rss/news/{from?}', function () {
        $locale = Config::get('app.locale');
        $title = $locale=="ru" ? 'title' : 'title_'.$locale;
        $full_text = $locale=="ru" ? 'full_text' : 'full_text_'.$locale;
        $news = \App\Models\News::where('published', true)->whereRaw('LENGTH('.$title.')>0')->whereRaw('LENGTH('.$full_text.')>0')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
        $feed = Rss::feed('2.0', 'UTF-8');
        $feed->channel([
            'title' => "News",
            'description' => "News description",
            'link' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        ]);

        foreach ($news as $row){
            $feed->item([
                'title' => $row->title,
                'description|cdata' => $row->full_text,
                'link' => route('news.show', ['slug' => $row->slug, 'id' => $row->id])
            ]);
        }
        return response($feed, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    });

    Route::post('/echo', 'ReservationController@index');
    //social auth
    Route::post('/feedback', 'FeedbackController@submit');
    Route::get('/social/redirect/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@getSocialRedirect')->name('social.redirect');
    Route::get('/social/handle/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@getSocialHandle')->name('social.handle');
    //verify email
    Route::get('/verify/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@activateUser');
    Route::get('/rating', 'RatingController@index')->name('rating');
    Route::get('/forecast', 'UserArea\ForecastController@show')->name('forecast');
    Route::get('/help', function(){return view('pages.totalizator.help.help');})->name('help');
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/competition'], function(){
        Route::get('/prizes', function(){
            return view('pages.acb.competition.prizes');
        })->name('competition.prizes');
        Route::get('/rules', function(){
            return view('pages.acb.competition.rules');
        })->name('competition.rules');
        Route::get('/winners', function(){
            return view('pages.acb.competition.winners');
        })->name('competition.winners');
    });

    Route::get('/get_next_tournament/{tournament_id}','UserArea\ForecastController@get_next_tournament');
    Route::get('/get_next_tournament_results/{tournament_id}','UserArea\ForecastController@get_next_tournament_results');
    Route::post('/update_data', 'Auth\UpdateController@updateData')->name('public.update_data');
    Route::get('/get_tournament_rating/{tournament_id}','RatingController@get_tournament_rating');
    Route::get('/get_sorted_ratings/{year}/{season}','RatingController@get_sorted_ratings');
    Route::get('/get_more_tournament_ratings/{tournament_id}/{current}','RatingController@get_more_tournament_ratings');
    Route::get('/get_more_sorted_ratings/{year}/{season}/{current}','RatingController@get_more_sorted_ratings');

    Route::post('/remember_email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendEmail')->name('remember_email');
    Route::any('/optimized_images', 'OptimizeImagesController@handle')->name('optimized_images');    //command get optimized images
    Route::post('/will_optimize_images', 'OptimizeImagesController@handle');//command get to optimize images
    if(env('APP_DEBUG')=='local'){
        Route::get('/t', function(){
            $backupCmd = new \App\Console\Commands\BackupFilesCommand();
            $backupCmd->handle();
        });
    }
    Route::get('/faq', 'FaqController@index')->name('faq');
    Route::get('/journalists', 'ConferenceController@journalists')->name('journalists');
//  Route::get('/conference', 'ConferenceController@index')->name('conference');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(), 'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect','web','localeGeoRedirect','localeOtherModules', 'seo']], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('user/activation/{token}', 'Auth\AuthController@activateUser')->name('user.email_activate');

    /*
     *  Admin pages
     */
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
        Route::get('', ['as' => 'admin.home',     'uses' => function(){return view('admin.index');}]);
        Route::get('/index', ['as' => 'admin.home',     'uses' => function(){return view('admin.index');}]);
        /*Route::get('/counrty_read', function(){
            $countries = App\Models\Country::where('id','>',0)->get();
            foreach($countries as $country){
                echo($country->slug.' удалена<br/>');
                $country->delete();
            }
            $lines=File::get('country.txt');
            $lines=explode('@',$lines);

            foreach($lines as $line)
            {
                $line = explode('/',$line);

                $flag=new \App\Models\Country(['name'=>$line[0],'name_en'=>$line[1],'slug'=>strtolower($line[2])]);
                $flag->save();
                echo($flag->name.' создан<br/>');

            }
        });*/
        Route::resource('/polls', 'Admin\PollsController');
        Route::resource('/faqs', 'Admin\FaqController');
        Route::resource('/conferences', 'Admin\ConferenceController');
        Route::resource('/promos', 'Admin\PromoPageController');
        Route::resource('/confphotos', 'Admin\ConfPhotoController');
        Route::resource('/confvideos', 'Admin\ConfVideoController');
        Route::resource('/achievements', 'Admin\AchievementController');
        Route::resource('/achievement_categories', 
        'Admin\AchievementCategoriesController');
        Route::resource('/avatars', 'Admin\AvatarController');
        Route::resource('/points', 'Admin\PointsController');
        Route::resource('/ranks', 'Admin\RankController');
        Route::get('/country/json/{id}', function($id){
            $country = App\Models\Country::findOrFail($id);
            return $country->cities->toArray();
        });
        Route::resource('/main_page', 'Admin\MainPageController');
        Route::resource('/city', 'Admin\CityController');
        Route::resource('/weightcategory', 'Admin\WeightCategoryController');
        Route::get('/weightcategory/clear/{id}', 'Admin\WeightCategoryController@clear');
        Route::get('/weightcategory/public/{data}-{hide}', 'Admin\WeightCategoryController@check');
        Route::resource('/combatstyle', 'Admin\CombatStyleController');
        Route::resource('/partner', 'Admin\PartnerController');
        Route::resource('/fighter', 'Admin\FighterController', ['names'=>
            [
                'index' => 'admin.fighter.index',
                'store' => 'admin.fighter.store',
                'create'=> 'admin.fighter.create',
                'update'=> 'admin.fighter.update',
                'show'  => 'admin.fighter.show',
                'destroy'=>'admin.fighter.destroy',
                'delete'=> 'admin.fighter.delete',
                'edit'  => 'admin.fighter.edit',
            ]
        ]);
        Route::resource('/fighter_rank', 'Admin\FighterRankController');
        Route::get('/fighter/public/{data}-{hide}', 'Admin\FighterController@check');
        Route::get('/tournament/public/{data}-{hide}', 'Admin\TournamentController@check');
        Route::get('/news/public/{data}-{hide}', 'Admin\NewsController@check');
        Route::resource('/tournament', 'Admin\TournamentController', ['names'=>
      [
          'index' => 'admin.tournament.index',
          'store' => 'admin.tournament.store',
          'create'=> 'admin.tournament.create',
          'update'=> 'admin.tournament.update',
          'show'  => 'admin.tournament.show',
          'destroy'=>'admin.tournament.destroy',
          'delete'=> 'admin.tournament.delete',
          'edit'  => 'admin.tournament.edit',
      ]
        ]);
        Route::resource('/tournament_review', 'Admin\TournamentReviewController');
        Route::resource('/album', 'Admin\AlbumController');
        Route::get('/album/public/{data}-{hide}', 'Admin\AlbumController@check');
        Route::get('/album/unique_num/{number}', 'Admin\AlbumController@unique_num');
        Route::get('/album/change_num/{id}/{number}', 'Admin\AlbumController@change_num');
        Route::resource('/fight', 'Admin\FightController');
        Route::get('/fight/clear/{fight_id}', 'Admin\FightController@clear');
        Route::resource('/media', 'Admin\MediaController');
        Route::resource('/news', 'Admin\NewsController', ['names'=>
            [
                'index' => 'admin.news.index',
                'store' => 'admin.news.store',
                'create'=> 'admin.news.create',
                'update'=> 'admin.news.update',
                'show'  => 'admin.news.show',
                'destroy'=>'admin.news.destroy',
                'delete'=> 'admin.news.delete',
                'edit'  => 'admin.news.edit',
            ]
        ]);
        /*Route::get('/user_achievements_test', 'UserTestController@achievements');
        Route::post('/save_achievements', 'UserTestController@saveachievements');
        */
        Route::get('/set_user_achievements_manually','Admin\UserController@set_user_achievements');
        Route::resource('/media_ajax', 'Admin\MediaAjaxController');
        Route::resource('/users', 'Admin\UserController');
        //SEO
        Route::resource('/seo', 'Admin\SeoController');
        Route::get('/user_achievements_test', 'UserTestController@achievements');
        Route::get('/check_forecasts/{tournament_id}/{user_id}','Admin\ForecastController@check_forecasts');
        Route::get('/get_user_list/{tournament_id}','Admin\ForecastController@get_user_list');
        Route::get('/check_tournament_results/{tournament_id}','Admin\ForecastController@check_tournament_results');
        Route::post('/save_achievements', 'UserTestController@saveachievements');
        Route::get('/set_users_achievements','Admin\ForecastController@set_users_achievements');

        Route::get("/users_list", function(){
            mb_http_output("UTF-8");
            ob_start("mb_output_handler");
            $users = \App\User::all()->toArray();
            # add headers for each column in the CSV download
            array_unshift($users, array_keys($users[0]));

            $headers = [
                'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
                ,   'Content-type'        => 'text/csv'
                ,   'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=users.csv'
                ,   'Expires'             => '0'
                ,   'Pragma'              => 'public'
                ,   'charset'             => 'utf-8'
            ];

            $callback = function() use ($users){
                $delimiter = ";";
                // open the "output" stream
                // see http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-unknown-descriptioq
                $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
                fprintf($f, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));

                fputcsv($f, $users[0], $delimiter);
                foreach ($users as $line) {
                    if(!isset($line['email']) || strpos($line['email'],"@")===FALSE) continue;
                    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter);
                }
                fclose($f);
            };
            return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
        });

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        Route::get("/{page?}/{subpage?}", ['middleware' => 'auth' , function ( $page='index', $subpage=null ){
            $page = mb_strtolower($page);
            $subpage = $subpage ? mb_strtolower($subpage) : null;
            $pages = ['index', 'seo', 'articles', 'gallery', 'profile'];
            $subpages = ['edit'];//дальдль
            if(in_array($page, $pages)){
                return view("admin.".$page);
            }
            return abort(404);
        }]);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/user', 'middleware' => ['auth_user']], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'user.home', 'uses' => 'UserArea\ProfileController@index']);
        Route::get('/avatars', ['as' => 'user.avatars', 'uses'=>'UserArea\ProfileController@avatars']);
        Route::get('/set_avatar/{avatar_id}', ['as'=>'user.set_avatar', 'uses'=>'UserArea\ProfileController@set_avatar']);
        Route::post('/update', 'UserArea\ProfileController@update_user');
        Route::get('/set_forecast_fighter/{fight_id}/{fighter_id}',  ['as'=>'user.forecast.figter', 'uses'=>'UserArea\ForecastController@set_forecast_fighter']);
        Route::get('/set_forecast_victory_type/{fight_id}/{victory_type}', ['as'=>'user.forecast.victory_type', 'uses'=>'UserArea\ForecastController@set_forecast_victory_type']);
        Route::get('/set_forecast_victory_round/{fight_id}/{victory_round}', ['as'=>'user.forecast.victory_round', 'uses'=>'UserArea\ForecastController@set_forecast_victory_round']);
        Route::post('/update_password','UserArea\ProfileController@update_password');
        Route::post('/update_email','UserArea\ProfileController@update_email');
        Route::get('/results',['as'=> 'user.results','uses' => 'UserArea\ForecastController@results']);
        Route::get('/get_user_tournament_rating/{tournament_id}','UserArea\ProfileController@get_user_tournament_rating');
        Route::get('/get_user_sorted_ratings/{year}/{season}','UserArea\ProfileController@get_user_sorted_ratings');
        Route::resource('/address','UserArea\AddressController', ['names'=>
            [
                'index' => 'user.address.index',
                'store' => 'user.address.store',
                'create'=> 'user.address.create',
                'update'=> 'user.address.update',
                'show'  => 'user.address.show',
                'destroy'=>'user.address.destroy',
                'delete'=> 'user.address.delete',
                'edit'  => 'user.address.edit',
            ]
        ]);
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => '/api_v1', 'middleware' => ['api']], function (){
        Route::get('/cities', 'ApiController@cities');
        Route::get('/tournaments', 'ApiController@tournaments');
        Route::get('/fight_voting', 'ApiController@fight_voting');
        Route::get('/tournaments_select', 'ApiController@tournaments_select');
        Route::get('/tournament_min/{tournament}', 'ApiController@tournament_min');
        Route::get('/tournaments_without_cities', 'ApiController@tournaments_without_cities');
        Route::get('/fighters_for_filter', 'ApiController@fighters_for_filter');
        Route::post('/register_on_conference', 'FeedbackController@register')->name('register_on_conference');
        Route::post('/register_on_conference_journalists', 'FeedbackController@registerJournalists')->name('register_on_conference_journalists');
    });
});
```

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` попробуйте

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: покажи полностью web.php или где у тебя роуты?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил роуты.

Comment: так там локаль ещё нужна типа `/ru/media/photo` получиться ссылку через `url('media.photo')` получи и смотри что там будет

Comment: Пробовал, это не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Все решил, просто не заметил что в .htaccess был редирект с media/photo на /photo и по этому когда заходили на страницу /media/photo начинался выполняться редирект на /photo а такой страницы у нас уже нет, и из-за этого получалась 404 ощибка.